# Deserialize XML into a object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

Hey everybody i can't deserialize this xml ,having this XML.

```
string xmlString = "<products>
<product><Id>1</Id><Name>My XML product</Name></Product>
<product><Id>2</Id><Name>My second product</Name></Product>
</products>";
```

This class:

```
public class Product
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To deserialize:

```
XmlSerializer serializer  = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>), new XmlRootAttribute("products"));
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
List<Product> productList = (List<Product>)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

The problem is i can't access to every "< product >" element in xml and the reason is the element in the XML should be  Capitalized to match with the class on the code.

How can i access to product ? not changing either the class to "product" or the element in the XMl to "< Product >".

I already tried:

```
[XmlRoot("product")]
public class Product
{...
```

I think this doesnt work because isnt a root element.

Comment: The Net Library will not deserialize a type List<Product> at the root.  A well formed XML only has one root node (not an array or list).  You need to create two classes.  One for Products and a second for Product.

Answer (score 1):

XML is case sensitive so there is no setting for the XmlSerializer to ignore the case , but here is a workaround, just do this before serializing:

```
xmlString ==xmlString.Replace("product>","Product>");
```